# Part of foreach in tpl.php of the View acts strange

Tags: views, theming

I created foreach in tpl.php of the View and it looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php foreach($view->result as $result): ?>
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="<?php print file_create_url($result->field_field_client_image[0]['raw']['uri']); ?>" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

My View has only one image field. Now I have two nodes and each of them have only one image, as output I should get:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

but I got:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image_2" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 no-pad"><img src="link_to_image" class="img-responsive"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

which is very strange.

My content type that I'm showing through Views has only one field for image and it is limited on 1 image file only.

Does someone have any idea what is the possible problem?

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable javascript? Could be a plugin.

Comment: Let me know if you need help solving it